# Python (or not...) framework for GPU / parallel ray tracing?

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, simulation, raytracing

I'm doing tech research for my next project, and haven't found anything suitable yet, so I'm giving SO a try.

The problem I'm looking to solve is the following:

- I have many (hundreds / thousands) of procedurally generated scenes, each consisting of ~10k cubes.
- In each of them I would like to check 1k-10k rays and get statistics on hit distance.
- This is not a rendering problem - the rays do not all originate from the same position. (So depth-pass based ray tracing is less suitable)
- Performance matters. I would like the underlying code to be either GPU based or parallelizable C.

Is there a framework that allows me to do such things? I looked at game engines but mostly don't raytrace.
I prefer to find a python framework framework that does this, but will settle on other languages (C# / C++) as well.

What would be the best way to tackle such a problem?

Comment: You can easily do this in Unity. We support ray tracing. You could also implement it yourself within a scene. There are a number of samples online showing how to populate a texture from a compute shader.

Comment: Thanks! The closest case I found was this:
https://github.com/superdump/unity-compute-shader-ray-tracer
However it ray traces by testing against every object (warns about scenes with over few hundred traingles), and i'm not sure it is parallelizable (fire 10000 rays, wait for results, process).
I would expect there to be some algorithm that pre-processes a scene to create a more efficient ray pathing solution and then use that... Maybe I'm overly optimistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. After quite a bit of research we ended up going with Trimesh ( https://trimsh.org/trimesh.html ).

It includes

- Interopability with popular geometry formats (gltf, obj, dae)
- Support for fast ray tracing by using pyembree (based on Intel's embree project)
- Supports batch queries (send X ray queries, get X ray answers back) to avoid the python<->C communication bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Which game engines did you looked for? Because Unreal and Unity two of most popular engines in market does already have support. In Python find a good lib or framework may be harder because Python doesn't have a great ecossystem around game engines.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/RayTracing/index.html

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/RayTracing/RayTracingSettings/index.html

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introducing-ray-tracing-in-unreal-engine-4/

https://unity.com/ray-tracing

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.1/manual/Ray-Tracing-Getting-Started.html

Update:

There's an engine in Python called PyGame that it's open source and might have some support, but I'm not sure if it's stable.

https://www.pygame.org/project/4743/6980

After some research I also found a package in Python that might work without a game engine, you could give a try

https://pypi.org/project/ntracer/

Comment: Thanks for the resources! I am well aware of ray tracing in games. The difference between my use case and what is popular in games, is that game engine ray tracing is always used for a single source (camera) usecase. The entire sampling strategy is based on that. In my case, I will fire 30-50 rays from ~100 source points per scene, making these approaches perform poorly.